# Refrigerator Ice Maker

Tags: refrigerator, ice-maker

I have an Frigidaire side by side refrigerator with a built in ice maker.  I was in the midst of moving and unable to hook up the water line for over a week.  My wife says it used to make a sound every once in a while but it no longer does so.  Does anyone know if I damaged it by not having a water line connected?

Comment: Is the water line connected now? Does it make ice? Is the ice maker turned on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no water line is connected then it will not make ice. The making of ice is the sounds your wife heard, so that's why she no longer hears anything. It does no harm to have it disconnected and once you reconnect it, it should begin producing ice again.